# Fetch data from a site through JS and save in a dict

Tags: javascript, api

I want to get some data from https://api.memegen.link/templates through Javascript. Can someone point me in the right direction or give me some sample code? I want to get all the `name` and `blank` and store it in a dictionary.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we are getting a random number ( first line ). Then we are using the `fetch()` API to get the JSON data from the website. Then we are converting the data to json, then we are choosing a random Object from the array and then logging the `name` and the `blank` to the console.
This is the way to get one item.

```js
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
fetch("https://api.memegen.link/templates")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
         console.log(data[random].name);
         console.log(data[random].blank);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

To put all the data to a dict you'll need to do this

```js
fetch("https://api.memegen.link/templates")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
    // The line below is a declaration of a array
            let items = [];
    // Getting every object from the array and pushing the names and images to OUR array
                data.forEach(item => {
                items.push({ name: item.name, blank: item.blank });
        });
    // Logging the array
        console.log(items);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton dude, it worked

Comment: No problem man. Glad it helped :)